# What datastructure best to use to aggregate data?

Tags: c++, collections, std

I have a tree of things that get asked what data they have, coming from the root.

Technically I have lists of items and I want to put these lists together and also sometimes check through all lists if the items contained in them changed since the last call I made to them.

Right now I use a function akin to

```c
virtual std::vector<MyProject::Item *> get_stuff(param_t query);
```

With an implementation often times akin to

```c
std::vector<MyProject::Item *> get_stuff(param_t query) {
    std::vector<MyProject::Item *> result;
    for(Item *i : this->inner_collection) {
        std::vector<MyProject::Item *> inner = i->get_stuff(query);
        result.insert(result.end(), inner.start(), inner.end());
    }
    return result;
}
```

As seen above I use a `std::vector` to pass this along. Is there a better collection type to do these queries? One that is way better and easier to program with when needing to append stuff to one another quite often?

Comment: can you be little bit more clear about what you are trying to do?

Comment: You could consider dictionaries when you want more freedom in the indexing/querying, but it depends on what you'd like to achieve with what kind of data. IMHO this is a good item for Code Review.. I see no issues with above code.. Refer https://codereview.stackexchange.com/